# C++11: is there any user-relatable thread ID?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I'm on g++ version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) running on Fedora release 31 (Thirty One).  I'm linking with `-pthread`.

`cout << std::thread:get_id()` prints numbers like `140737177954048` .  However GDB outputs thread numbers like `2`.  Is GDB outputting some other ID I too could be outputting?  The use is to put thread IDs of the thread generating a log message into the log file so that they can be followed later for debugging, and these 15-digit numbers are likely too hard to read and track as well as taking up a lot of room.

My alternative was to have the log module detect new threads and simply assign an sequentially-incrementing number (`atomic<unsigned int>` that I CAS).  The app in question only has long-lived threads, so I needn't worry about near-infinite numbers of short-lived threads pumping up this counter to unreadable value levels.  But if there's something better let me know!

Comment: I don't think GDB prints thread id:s but just a sequence number that'll be increased the more threads you start so your alternative sounds like a feasable solution. You could store the active threads in a `std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, size_t>`

Comment: The log library checks if a thread_local context struct is init'd.  If not it increments the global log module's context's thread counter with an atomic CAS and uses that.  I don't know how thread_local is usually implmented though; is it doing a hash table lookup internally, do you think?

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. If the compiler is cleaver enough to figure out how many thread_local's you have from start I guess it could make a lookup table of some sort  already when compiling I like the idea of using a thread_local for this. it could be quicker than a map so measure the performance.

Comment: Thread's have meta data associated with them (on Windows it's the TEB) which is generally pointed to by the fs or gs selectors for x86. Thread local storage is just a pointer in that metadata. At least that's how it generally works on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Wouldn't want to take a bet on what's more efficient (in reality it's a negligible overhead in any case), but remember to lock the hashmap when reading or writing to it.